# How does making the virtual address contiguous in physical address zone improve performance?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, dpdk, huge-pages

Recently I am reading code about hugepage in dpdk(dpdk.org). I see the code  makes the virtual address contiguous in physical address zone on purpose. Specifically, it first checks if there exists physically contiguous zone in hugepages and map the physically contiguous zone into contiguous virtual address. How does this improve the performance?

The [source code](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/master/lib/librte_eal/linux/eal/eal_memory.c) says:

> To reserve a big contiguous amount of memory, we use the hugepage feature of linux. For that, we need to have hugetlbfs mounted. This code will create many files in this directory (one per page) and map them in virtual memory. For each page, we will retrieve its physical address and remap it in order to have a virtual contiguous zone as well as a physical contiguous zone.

Why is this remapping necessary?

Comment: https://linuxgazette.net/155/krishnakumar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> map the physically contiguous zone into contiguous virtual address. How does this improve the performance?

DPDK needs both physical and virtual addresses. The virtual address is used normally, to load/store some data. The physical address is necessary for the userspace drivers to transfer data to/from devices.

For example, we allocate a few `mbuf`s with virtual addresses `0x41000`, `0x42000` and `0x43000`. Then we fill them with some data and pass those virtual addresses to the PMD to transfer.

The driver has to convert those virtual addresses to physical. If physical pages are mapped to virtual address space noncontiguous, to convert virtual to physical addresses we need to search through all the mappings. For example, virtual address `0x41000` might correspond to physical `0x81000`, `0x42000` corresponds to `0x16000`, and `0x43000` — to `0x64000`.

The best case of such a search is one memory read, the worst case — **a few memory reads for each buffer**.

But if we are sure that both virtual and physical addresses of a memory zone are contiguous, we simply add an offset to the virtual address to get the physical and vice versa. For example, virtual `0x41000` corresponds to `0x81000`, virtual `0x42000` to physical `0x82000`, and `0x43000` — `0x83000`.

The offset we know from the mapping. The worst case of such a translation is **one memory read per all the buffers in a burst**, which is a huge improvement for the translation.

> Why is this remapping necessary?

To map a huge page to a virtual address space an `mmap` system call is used. The API of the call allows to specify the fixed virtual address for the huge page to be mapped. This allows to map huge pages one after another creating a **contiguous virtual memory zone**. For example, we can `mmap` a huge page at the virtual address `0x200000`, the next one at the virtual address `0x400000` and so on.

Unfortunately, we don't know physical addresses of the huge pages until they are mapped. So at the virtual address `0x200000` we might map the physical address `0x800000`, and at the virtual address `0x400000` — the physical `0x600000`.

But once we mapped those huge pages for the first time, we know both physical and virtual addresses. So all we **need to do is to remap them in the correct order:** at virtual address `0x1200000` we map physical `0x600000`, and at `0x1400000` — physical `0x800000`.

Now we have a virtually and physically contiguous memory zone starting at the virtual address `0x1200000` and physical address `0x600000`. So to convert virtual to physical addresses in this memory zone we just need to subtract the offset `0x600000` from the virtual address as described previously.

Hope this clarifies a bit the idea of contiguous memory zones and remapping.

Comment: hi, berestovskyy. Perfect answer! But there is still something I don't quite understand: you said the contiguous mapping brings 'one memory read in a burst'. But how will this happen when the process access so much memory (multiple hugepages). In my understanding, if the process want to access some element in the memory, it goes through the TLB or the whole page table. I think this is what you said by 'translation'. So if the element is inside one hugepage, the contiguous mapping does not work. Only the element is in two or more hugepages, the contigous mapping will work. Is that right?

Comment: @4va1anch3 the TLB is a completely different story. It's still there anyway and huge pages really improve TLB performance by using much bigger pages and hence much less translations.

But DPDK is a userspace application which also needs virtual-to-physical address translation. So it does it in software, not with TLB. If we are sure that all the virtual and physical addresses of a DPDK's memory zone are contiguous, we can do the translation in software by just adding an offset as described in the answer.

Comment: Now I totally understand! Thanks a lot!